# The average rate of change of a function

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

The following is a multiple-choice question in the 2014 AP Calculus BC exam paper.

> The function $f$ is given by $$f(x) = \int_{1}^{x}{\sqrt{t^3+2}} \,{\rm d }t$$ What is the average rate of change of $f$ over the interval $[0, 3]$? 
> $(A) 1.324  \hspace{0.4 in} (B) 1.497 \hspace{0.4 in} (C) 1.696 \hspace{0.4 in} (D) 2.266 \hspace{0.4 in} (E) 2.694$

---

The answer is E.

I know that if a function $f(x) = \int_{a}^{b} g(x)\,{\rm d }x$, then the average rate of change of $f$ over the interval $[a, b]$ is
\begin{equation}
f'_{ave} = \frac{1}{b-a}\frac{{\rm d }}{{\rm d }x}\int_{a}^{b}g(x)\,{\rm d }x= \frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}
\end{equation}
But in this question, the range of integration is $[1, x]$ which is different from the interval $[0, 3]$ to be averaged over; besides, in the interval $[0, 1]$, the function $f$ is not given. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The average of $f$ is given by $$\frac{1}{3}\int_0^3\int_1^x\sqrt{t^3+2}\,\mathrm d t\,\mathrm d x.$$

Comment: Note in your definition of $f(x)$, the RHS does not even depend on $x$...

Answer (score 1):

The average derivative of $f$ over $[0,3]$ is $$\frac1{3-0}\int_0^3f'(x)\,\mathrm dx,$$ which, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, is $$\frac1{3-0}\int_0^3\sqrt{x^3+2}\,\mathrm dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

$G(x) = \int_1^x f(t)\;dt = F(x) - F(1)$

Average rate of change of G(x), x from 0 to 3:

$\displaystyle \frac{G(3)-G(0)}{3-0}
= \frac{F(3)-F(0)}{3-0}
= \frac{1}{3} \int_0^3 f(x)\;dx $